# pipenv only installs .venv in home directory

Tags: python, pipenv

Trying `pipenv` for the first time:

```
> cd ~
> mkdir foo
> cd foo
> pipenv install
> pipenv --venv
> [/Users/richardlyon/.venv]
> cd ..
> mkdir bar
> cd bar
> pipenv install
> pipenv --venv
> [/Users/richardlyon/.venv]
```

I cannot relate this to my reading of the `pipenv` manual, which suggests that a separate virtual environment should created for each directory in which `pipenv` is invoked. Nor can I see the advantage of this arrangement.

Could anyone shed any light? Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

OK. Looks like fiddling around had created file `Pipfile` in the root which was making `pipenv` treat root as an existing virtual environment. Deleting it fixed the problem.

Leaving this here in case anyone else (new) comes across this - it didn't show up as an issue in a web search.

Comment: Your answer is actually quite important... I also had a Pipefile and a Pipefile.lock in my home folder (no idea why) and whenever I wanted now to create a new environment in a folder, it would switch to the env of my home folder. Removing the two files solved it.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see why pipenv stopped working for new projects. I think I accidentally created and deleted a virtual environment at user root, but did not notice the remaining Pipfile or consider one could cause this problem.

Comment: Any solution this yet??? After some updates my pipenv started using home directory to store `Pipfile` and `Piplock`. Also for any new environments it assign name of root to the environment name with some gibberish extensions.

Comment: OK update! I went ahead and removed `Pipfile` and `Piplock` in my home directory. After then, when I ran `pipenv install` in a subdirectory where I have my new project,  it created environment files in my project folder. It was referring to the `Pipfile` in my home directory whenever I run `pipenv install` in any new project. Also now it is assigning the project name as an environment name!

Comment: @UrsinBrunner Thanks mate, removing those files helped in my case as well

Answer (score 0):

I am using `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=True pipenv install` to install in current folder.

Comment: This doesn't help either!